# Merge 2 arrays in change

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I wanted to merge two arrays like you can fold 2 packs of cards - in ugly code with for loop and assuming same length so no if's for safety it would look like this:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const rra = [4,5,6];
const result = [];

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  result.push(arr[i],rra[i]);
}

console.log(result); // Array(6) [ 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6 ]
```

I know there is something similar in String.raw() but it cuts off last element and returns a string, is there equivalent in array ?

```js
String.raw({raw: [1,2,3]}, ...[4,5,6]); //"14253"
```

Comment: what is actually the question? [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) is to work with template literals.

Comment: can I merge two arrays like with the for loop above but in 1 line with some built in method/function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this - This is the same as `.map()`, followed by `.flat()`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const rra = [4,5,6];

let newArray = arr.flatMap((ele, i) => [ele, rra[i]]);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: sorry for late mark as good answer, just realised I can do that. And obviously great answer just what I was looking for back then